# Can't align line charts according to Y axis

Tags: java, dynamic-reports

I tried to create 2 line chart using line chart of dynamic reports.

[Y axes of 2 graphs are not aligned.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oz4KF.jpg)

I want to align these charts according to Y axis.

```
LineChartBuilder lineChart1 = cht.lineChart()
                .setCategory(itemColumn)
                .setShowValues(false)
                .setTitle("Line chart")
                .setCategoryAxisFormat(cht.axisFormat()
                        .setLabel("Item"))
                .setShowShapes(false)
                .series(cht.serie(detectsColumn));

        LineChartBuilder lineChart2 = cht.lineChart()
                .setCategory(itemColumn)
                .setShowValues(false)
                .setTitle("Line chart")
                .setCategoryAxisFormat(cht.axisFormat()
                        .setLabel("Item"))
                .setShowShapes(false)
                .series(cht.serie(rangeColumn));

        try {
            report().setTemplate(Templates.reportTemplate)
                    .title(Templates.createTitleComponent("My Report"))
                    .summary(lineChart1, lineChart2)
                    .pageFooter(Templates.footerComponent)
                    .setDataSource(createDataSource())
                    .show();
        } catch (DRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```